# Get Google Analytics A/B style results on any page of website?

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to get the conversion rate for an individual page just like you get when running an A/B test. I want to find out how many times /page hits the goal of going to /thanks after a visitor is on it. I have tried a custom report but the only page that shows conversion rate stats is the actual thanks page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom segment of your users or sessions, who have visited a given page, or groups of pages. (Look for Conditions under Advanced group of New segment dialog.) You can filter your standard or custom reports for this segment only, and get the information, you are looking for.

Comment: This gets me close. From what I can tell this shows me goals completed is they hit the page I specify in my segment within their session. Is there any way to get direct conversions? So they hit "/page-a" then hit the goal of "/thanks". I'm looking for a direct conversion from that page for this report instead of conversions if they hit that page in their session.

Comment: There might be an other solution for your need. If you specify a Goal for /thanks page, you can set up a funnel for that. (Turn on Funnel in Goal details section.) You can specify preceding step(s), and specify the first one (/page-a in your case) as required one. You can analyse Goal Flow reports, and see users' progress among funnel steps. This will also show you other pages, that are visited instead of pages in your funnel.